# Number to words in VBA. Insert "and" for the last figure

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to add the word "and" before the last figure but unable to do so.

> Eg: $101 (One Hundred and One)
>
> $110 (One Hundred and Ten)
>
> $111.50 (One Hundred Eleven and Fifty)

```
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
    
    Dim Result As String
    
    If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
    
    ' Convert the hundreds place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
        
        Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
           
    End If
    
           
    ' Convert the tens and ones place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
        
        Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
        
    Else
    
        Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
        
    End If
    
    GetHundreds = Result
    
End Function
```

Comment: What's the error ? Did you try debugging the Code using `F8`. ?

Comment: I don't think you want to insert it before the last figure. Otherwise 110 would be "one hundred ten and zero".

Answer (score 0):

It is not encourged to add an "and" after hundreders in a number. However, to assist you I have modified the function I posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223615/very-simple-spell-number-to-words-001-to-999-in-vba  so that it will add an "and".

The function deals with numbers from 001 to 999. No fractions. For numbers with fractions you will need to split the number and deal with each part (the whole number and the fraction part) separately; once split, it is easy to add an "and" before a fraction.

Here it is . I hope it works and gets you starting

```
'-------------------------------------
Function Do999(ByVal ThreeDigits) As String
'-------------------------------------
'Spells numbers from 001 to 999 to Words
'Mohsen Alyafei 17 Oct 2018
'Modified to add "and" by Mohsen Alyfei 07 July 2019
'On Entry: ThreeDigits 3 digit number 001 to 999
'On Exit : String of number in English words
'-----------------------------------------
    Dim Ones(), Tens(), Separator  As String, h As String, t As String, N1 As Integer, N2 As Integer, annd As String
    Ones = Array("", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen")
    Tens = Array("", "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety")

    ThreeDigits = Right("000" & ThreeDigits, 3)  'Align to 3 digits
    annd = " "           'added to add "and"

    If Right(ThreeDigits, 1) <> "0" Then Separator = "-"

    N1 = Left(ThreeDigits, 1): N2 = Right(ThreeDigits, 2)
    If N2 > 19 Then t = Tens(Val(Mid(ThreeDigits, 2, 1))) & Separator & Ones(Val(Right(ThreeDigits, 1))) Else t = Ones(N2)

    If N1 > 0 Then
      h = Ones(N1) & " Hundred"
      If N2 > 0 Then annd = " and "     'added to add "and"
    End If
Do999 = Trim(h & annd & t)              'var "annd" is normally a space
End Function
```